# React.js, Material Ui Stepper direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a weird situation right here where I try to build a stepper component within my app.
everything goes well so far but I try to make this stepper to go from Right to left.
things I have tried:
I tried to instal i18next (translation library) and it didn't work out.
I tried to go from 3 down to 2, and it also is not a satisfying result

here is the result:
[image]

and here is my code:

```
import {
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
  createStyles,
  withStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import GroupAddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GroupAdd';
import VideoLabelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VideoLabel';
import StepConnector from '@material-ui/core/StepConnector';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { StepIconProps } from '@material-ui/core/StepIcon';

const ColorlibConnector = withStyles({
  alternativeLabel: {
    top: 22,
  },
  active: {
    '& $line': {
      backgroundImage:
        'linear-gradient( 95deg,rgb(242,113,33) 0%,rgb(233,64,87) 50%,rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
    },
  },
  completed: {
    '& $line': {
      backgroundImage:
        'linear-gradient( 95deg,rgb(242,113,33) 0%,rgb(233,64,87) 50%,rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
    },
  },
  line: {
    height: 3,
    border: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#eaeaf0',
    borderRadius: 1,
  },
})(StepConnector);

const useColorlibStepIconStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    zIndex: 1,
    color: '#fff',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  active: {
    backgroundImage:
      'linear-gradient( 136deg, rgb(242,113,33) 0%, rgb(233,64,87) 50%, rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
  },
  completed: {
    backgroundImage:
      'linear-gradient( 136deg, rgb(242,113,33) 0%, rgb(233,64,87) 50%, rgb(138,35,135) 100%)',
  },
});

function ColorlibStepIcon(props: StepIconProps) {
  const classes = useColorlibStepIconStyles();
  const { active, completed } = props;

  const icons: { [index: string]: React.ReactElement } = {
    1: <SettingsIcon />,
    2: <GroupAddIcon />,
    3: <VideoLabelIcon />,
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.active]: active,
        [classes.completed]: completed,
      })}
    >
      {icons[String(props.icon)]}
    </div>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: '100%',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    button: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    instructions: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    stepperContainer: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    contentContainer: {
      width: '50%',
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  })
);

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step: number) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return 'Select campaign settings...';
    case 1:
      return 'What is an ad group anyways?';
    case 2:
      return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

const SignUp: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.stepperContainer}>
        <Stepper
          dir="rtl"
          alternativeLabel
          activeStep={activeStep}
          connector={<ColorlibConnector />}
        >
          {steps.map((label) => (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel StepIconComponent={ColorlibStepIcon}>
                {label}
              </StepLabel>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>
      </div>

      <div className={classes.contentContainer}>
        <div>
          {activeStep === steps.length ? (
            <div>
              <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
              </Typography>
              <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                Reset
              </Button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                {getStepContent(activeStep)}
              </Typography>
              <div>
                <Button
                  disabled={activeStep === 0}
                  onClick={handleBack}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Back
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleNext}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I was fiddling around with the material UI sandbox,
[here's the sandbox with working left to right](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ew15o?file=/demo.tsx:0-4455)
things I've change, were:

- line 43 - initate step to 2
- line 62 - handleNext, prevActiveStep - 1 (from +1)
- line 67 - handleBack, prevActiveStep + 1 (from -1)
- line 86 - setActiveStep(2) (from setActiveStep(0))
- the Stepper component:

```js
<Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps: { completed?: boolean } = {
            completed: activeStep < index //  <<< this setting
          };
          const labelProps: { optional?: React.ReactNode } = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = (
              <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>
            );
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
</Stepper>
```

hope that helps

Comment: Hey, You did it, Thank you man you really saved my day